# Data is not rendering in Thymeleaf, Webflux

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-webflux

I am new to Webflux, I am not able to render data in thymeleaf, I have no clues, what is happening behind the scenes.

```
@GetMapping(value = "")
public String index(final Model model){
    final Flux<Post> postFlux = blogService.findAllPosts();

    // final IReactiveDataDriverContextVariable commentDataDriver = new ReactiveDataDriverContextVariable(postFlux, 1); // buffers size = 1
    model.addAttribute("blogs", blogService.findAllPosts());
    return "blogs";
}
```

Thymeleaf

```
<tr data-th-each="blg : ${blogs}">
   <td>[[${blg.title}]]</td>
</tr>
```

org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'title' cannot be found on object of type 'reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume' - maybe not public or not valid?

Howeever, when I tried to display [[${blg}]], it displays **FluxOnErrorResume**